# Combining multiple audio click JS functions into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

So i found a script and modified to it to work with what I need. But i need to do one more thing and not sure where to start with it.

Here is the code im using to get two different audio files to play with two different buttons

```
        $(document).on("click", "li", function(event) {
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3');

            //audioElement.load()
            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
            audioElement.play();
            }, true);

            $('.play-duck-1').click(function(event) {
            audioElement.play();
            });
        });

            $(document).on("click", "li", function(event) {
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://sandbox.acscreative.com/cort-aminals/sounds/new-recording.m4a');

            //audioElement.load()
            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
            audioElement.play();
            }, true);

            $('.play-duck-2').click(function(event) {
            audioElement.play();
            });
        });
```

is there a way to combine these scripts so I don't have to copy and paste this 36 times for 36 different audio files and buttons?

I have seen lots of "function combining" post but none that look like they would work me for unless im overlooking something.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Currently your two handlers will both run when an <li> is clicked. You need to detect which button has been clicked (using event.target) and determine the url from that. Does that sounds like what you're after?

Comment: I dont think so, here is my site http://sandbox.acscreative.com/cort-aminals/index.html. If you click on the duck + and click on the first two flags ( Belgium and China ) you can see they are both playing separate files. But I need to load 36 different files for 36 different flags and was just looking for a more efficient way to do it without copy and pasting 36 times.

Comment: OK, sharing the page helped me understand the structure a little more. I would suggest using `<a>` tags for each flag button with the `href` set to the audio file. You could then have one event listener which targets the general case of a sound button so you have one handler for all the animals and sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this,

```
var audList = [
    ...
];  // can be dynamic, fetched from somewhere
var parentElement = document.getElementById('btnParent');
var audio = new Audio();
audList.forEach(function(src){
    parentElement.appendChild(createBtnElement(src.img, src.audio));
});

function createBtnElement(imgSrc, audioSrc){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var btn = document.createElement('img');
    btn.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);
    btn.setAttribute('height', 80); // change as per requirement
    btn.setAttribute('width', 80); // change as per requirement
    btn.className = 'playAudio someCSSClass img-responsive';
    btn.onclick = function(){
        audio.src = audioSrc;
        audio.play();
    };
    li.appendChild(btn);
    return li;
}
```

This way, once you change the no. of audio files, you don't need to touch the HTML, just modify the `audList`, another advantage of doing this way is, no two songs would be played simultaneously because there is only one `Audio` object

#### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/haouwow1/5)

Comment: So this look nice, but how would I link this to my HTML images that you can see in the example below, i have a li with a image in it?

Answer (score 0):

this(event.target)As commented, you could have a single event handler that targets all audio buttons and infers the audio file to be played from the href of the audio link (so you don't need to hardcode the values in your JS)

```
$(document).on("click", ".sound", function(event) {
    // Stop browser following link
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get clicked link
    var link = this;

    // Create audio element with url from link
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        audioElement.play();
    }, true);
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', link.href);
    audioElement.load()
});
```

This would require wrapping your flag images in `<a>` tags with `class="sound"`:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="sound" href="http://example.com/sound1.mp4">
            <img src="images/duck-belgium.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sound" href="http://example.com/sound2.mp4">
            <img src="images/duck-china.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sound" href="http://example.com/sound3.mp4">
            <img src="images/duck-spain.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting that together but that just seems to link to the audio file, take a look back at my site and click on the duck then the first flag, just opens up the audio file that is in the URL

Comment: Ah, you'll need to do `event.preventDefault()` in the handler to stop the browser following the link. Updated answer.

Comment: now it does not open but it also does not play, update my code on the same sample link

Comment: Your site seems to be down (" Unavailable
Site temporarily unavailable.
Connection timed out - please try again.")

Comment: yea sorry my server just had a small burp, but its back now and i fell like this is the right track. Im new a JS so thanks for all the help so far

Comment: Try replacing `event.target` with `this` (`event.target ` represents the deepest element clicked - in this case your flag image, whereas `this` should represent the element targeted by the event handlers selector (`.sound`))

Comment: Your site seems to still be using `event.target`. I've updated my answer to show what I mean. edit: sorry, didn't see your edit. Almost right, see updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try moving the audioElement's load listener up before the .load() call (if the file is cached, the load event will fire straight away, before the listener is added).